# Graphs in which any two odd cycles have a common vertex

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a graph in which any two odd cycles have a common vertex. It is easy to see that $\chi(G)\leq 5$ (choose minimal odd cycle $C$, use two colors for $G\setminus C$ and three colors for $C$). And this is sharp as $K_5$ shows.
May we improve this bound to $\chi(G)\leq 4$ assuming additionally that $G$ does not contain $K_5$? Or to $\chi(G)\leq 3$ assuming that $G$ does not contain $K_4$? I can not prove even $\chi(G)\leq 4$ for $G$ without $K_3$.

Comment: The cycles need not be _induced_, right?

Comment: It does not matter, since any any odd cycle contains induced odd cycle.

Comment: If there are at most two odd cycles, and they have a common a vertex, then our graph is (bipartite plus a vertex), hence 3-colorable.

Comment: $G$ may be 4-chromatic even if it does not contain $K_3$. An example is provided by the Mycielski graph of $C_5$. To see that it does not contain two disjoint odd cycles, notice that each odd cycle either contains the apex and an edge of $C_5$, or contains at least one of any two neighbors in  $C_5$.

Comment: More generally, any non-bipartite quadrangulation of the projective plane is an example (any two odd cycles intersect, since they correspond to non-contractible curves on the surface), and it is known that they are 4-chromatic (D.A. Youngs, 4-chromatic projective graphs, J. Graph Theory 21 (1996), 219-227). The Mycielski graph is a particular case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The claim on graphs without $K_5$ is a particular case of the (still open in general) [Erdos--Lovasz Tihany conjecture](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/DecomposeToIncreaseChromaticNumber.html). (Tihany is not a surname, but the name of a peninsula on Balaton lake in Hungary.)

This particular case has been proved in [W.G. Brown and H.A. Jung, On odd circuits in chromatic graphs, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hungarica, V. 20(1), pp. 129-134](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01894573). In fact, this paper contains more general results.

As I already mentioned in the comments, this bound cannot be lowered to 3 even if the graph contains no $K_3$.  An example is provided by the Mycielski graph of $C_5$. To see that it does not contain two disjoint odd cycles, notice that each odd cycle either contains the apex and an edge of $C_5$, or contains at least one of any two neighbors in $C_5$.